# dom name for a textarea

Tags: javascript, dom, keyboard-shortcuts, simple-html-dom

I wanted to know how to get DOM Node of a textarea or a input field? I was using the JavaScript file to handle the keyboard shortcuts and I found that we can give a target of the shortcut that where to use that shortcut, default is to document, I have downloaded that JavaScript and wrote these samples,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="shortcut.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
shortcut.add("a",function() {
    alert("The bookmarks of your browser will show up after this alert...");
},{
    'type':'keydown',
    'disable_in_input':false,
    'propagate':false,
    'target':document.form1.namea
});</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1"><textarea name="namea" id="namea"></textarea></form>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this script from [here](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) now I need to when I put the target document and press the key "a" in my keyboard, it shows me an alert but if I put document.form1.namea like this then it don't show me any alert please help me out this. I also tried putting `document.getElementById("namea")` but no any help, in the tutorial it said that, in this option, we must give its 
***target - DOM Node

The element that should be watched for the keyboard event. Default : document***
I tried to Google about DOM node of my textarea but no any help, please help me out, I want to submit this form when user presses key "a" or I can modify it into enter key as well.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("namea")` will work … but not until the node exists.

You are running the script (with no delay (e.g. onload)) before the `<input>` element has been parsed.

Either make it a function that you call later, or move the `<script>` so it appears after the `<input>` (e.g. just before the `</body>` tag).

Comment: omg, why didnt i thought of this little thing, thanks for reminding me thanks a lot now it is working thanks again and thanks again a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully the sentence you've taken form the documentation:

> target - DOM Node The element that should be watched for the keyboard
>   event. Default : document

If you set the target to a differente element, the shorcut will only have effect if you are on that element. So, what you have to do is left the target as is (document) and change the alert by a

```
document.form1.submit()
```

Comment: sorry i didnt really meant that, i meant that, the shortcut should only work when user focus on that text area, if it is not focused then hitting a should not do anything but thanks, i knew that, i want to submit the form only if user has focused in the textarea and presses the key "a"